# Flutter BLoC:Global exception handler for mapEventToState

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I use felangel's bloc library. I fetch data by using a repository in mapEventToState method .If the repository throws an exception, I want to catch it on a global exception handler.

```
@override
Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(Event event) async* {
  if (event is MyEvent) {
    try {
      var data = await repository.fetchData();
      yield MyState(data);
    } catch (e) {
      //There may be many exceptions
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way catch exceptions without try-catch blocks and what is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a util for managing errors. I wrote something for this. It could be an idea for you.

```
static String handleError(Error error) {
        String errorDescription = "";
        if (/*error is SomethingError*/) {
          switch (error.type) {
            case ErrorType.CANCEL:
              errorDescription = "ErrorType.CANCEL";
              break;
            case ErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT:
              errorDescription = "ErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT";
              break;
            case ErrorType.DEFAULT:
              errorDescription = "ErrorType.DEFAULT";
              break;
            case ErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT:
              errorDescription = "ErrorType.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT";
              break;
            case ErrorType.RESPONSE:
              switch (error.response.toString()) {
                case "usernamePasswordFail":
                  errorDescription = "usernamePasswordFail";
                  break;
                default:
                  errorDescription = "errorDescription";
 }, ${error.response.data ?? ''}";
                  break;
              }
              break;
            case ErrorType.SEND_TIMEOUT:
              errorDescription = "ErrorType.SEND_TIMEOUT";
              break;
          }
        } else {
          errorDescription = "somethingElseError";
        }
        return errorDescription;
      }
```